capacitor issue in android platform
I am new in the web,android development world.
I am getting started on a project in Capacitor js, followed the instructions in the documentation when I run cap run android it crushed
Running Gradle build - failed!
[error] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not
be reused, use --status for details
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1.
    Required by:
    project :
    > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1 was found.
    The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime,
    compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared
    externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with
    value '8.2.1' but:
    - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1
    declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared

It work on Android Studio.
windows 11
in my environment variables i have:  
ANDROID HOME :  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20
      C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin
      C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8
JAVA HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8

I expect to have a solutions

You are currently using Java 8 but need to use Java 17 for Capacitor 6.

thank, can i solve this by updating java?

If your application runs in Android Studio, but not with the npx cap run command, the issue is generally about your JAVA_HOME environment variable. You have JAVA HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8, an older version of JAVA incompatible with the latest Capacitor.
The reason is, Android Studio installs its own JDK/JRE and uses it. However, your capacitor CLI might not recognise this version as it's not defined in the path. You can check which JAVA your Android Studio is using by checking the settings, see:finding-android-studio-java-path.
You can then, change your JAVA_HOME environment variable to use the same JAVA path as the Android Studio. see the tutorial to achieve this.

in android studio ->sitting -->build,execution,deployment --> build tool--> gradle there is : Gradle JDK: GRADLE_LOCAL_JAVA_HOME jetBrains Runtime version C:\Program File\Android\Android Studio\jbr then i update the upated JAVA HOME to same path but issue still
i got new errore:
i will put it down

Running Gradle build - failed!
[error] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 incompatible and 5 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Configure project :app WARNING: Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
Configure project :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins
WARNING: Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.


Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE

